# What is the meaning and the grammar behind the second sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I specifically need help understanding the "to recommend a wine firm in whose hands you could not go very far wrong" part. Thanks.

"Previous governesses had limited their conversation on the wine topic to a respectful and doubtless sincere expression of a preference for water. When this one went as far as to recommend a wine firm in whose hands you could not go very far wrong Mrs. Quabarl thought it time to turn the conversation into more usual channels."

Quote from the The Schartz-Metterklume Method by Saki, or H. H. Munro

Comment: Do you understand the sentence if you read _firm_ as a noun (= _wine business_) rather than as an adjective (= _hard, strong_)?

Comment: I listened to the audiobook and the voice narrator used firm as an adjective, but I'm still having trouble understanding.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _the voice narrator used firm as an adjective_?

Comment: There was a pause between wine and firm. For example, "When [the governess] went as far as to recommend a wine, firm in whose hands you could not go very far wrong, Mrs. Quabarl thought it time to turn the conversation into more usual channels."

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, the narrator paused between the words *wine* and *firm*, leading you to read *firm* as an adjective. This is an understandable assumption, but I think the narrator has led you astray on this.

The expression "*You can't go wrong in the hands of X*" is commonly used in advertising to indicate the quality of the product or service on offer. Here are a few examples:

> ... you can't go wrong in the hands of Chefs Alex and Mike
>   (http://scoutmob.com/atlanta/deals/1990)
>
> You can't go wrong in the hands of a Master Roaster!
>   (https://allevents.in/woodridge/starbucks-master-roaster-coffee-experience-inside-macys/198777784006100)
>
> ...in need of auto body work then you can't go wrong in the hands of
>   Kings County auto body shop.
>   (https://www.yelp.com/biz/kings-county-auto-body-brooklyn)

In this case, the governess is saying (in paraphrase):

> I recommend XX wine firm. You cannot go wrong in their hands.

Saki has made a relative clause out of the second sentence in the paraphrase. He could equally well have written:

> When this one went as far as to recommend a wine firm in the hands of
>   whom you could not go very far wrong,....

These constructions are formal, but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer makes perfect sense. I just looked up that phrase, and I understand the sentence so much better now that you explained it to me. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Ashly Chi. Since there is no comma between _wine_ and _firm_ in Saki's text, I don't understand why the narrator paused!

Comment: I think I misheard it. Now that I listen to it there isn't a pause. You can listen to it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ywmwzvGNrM at 2:10:40 and tell me what you think.

Comment: I don't hear a pause, but I think the slight overstressing  of _firm_ tends to impede the understanding of _wine firm_ as a single unit.